# How to show the amount of items in a table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables in a database, I would like to list all groups including a count of the number of people in each group. how would i do this?

so it should say:

```
group1 4
group2 5
group3 5
```

etc.

Comment: Can you explain this more? do you have any sql code that you have tried to run?

Comment: based on what you have shown (nothing useful), we have no clue how the 4 tables relate to give you a result. Research `count()` and `group by` and write **much** better questions

Comment: im using: select album_name from "album", count(*) from track group by album_name;

Comment: and am getting a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM group1;-->for each table
```

the line above returns the number of records in your table.

To list this information just use a list of strings, and each time your pushing

```
for(int i=1;i<=numberOfGroups;i++)
list.add("group"+"i");
int num = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM group"+i+"";
list.add(String.valueof(num));
```

This is my idea..